# cannot figure out how to update mailboxer is_read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I am using the mailboxer gem and I am trying to make it so that after i look at a conversation (by accessing conversations#show), I want the is_read attribute of the receipt to turn true.  However, the attribute will not turn true until I send a reply.  I tried using the following line:

```
receipt.update_attributes(is_read: true)
```

but was returned the following error:

```
Error (ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord)
```

I think I understand the error.  I think it is saying that the attribute can only be read and not updated.  My question is, how do I implement the functionality to have is_Read turn true if i go to the conversations#show page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of updating the is_read attribute try this

```
#conversations_controller.rb
def show
  @receipts = mailbox.receipts_for(conversation).not_trash
  @receipts.mark_as_read
end

private

def mailbox
    @mailbox ||= current_user.mailbox
end

def conversation
    @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
end
```

You can also mark a entire conversation as read with

```
conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `conversation.receipts_for(current_user).update_all(:is_read => true)'
in the`mark_as_read`  method worked for me.

```
def conversation
    if !params[:id] && @activeConvo
      @conversation = @activeConvo
    else
      @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```